# сдвигаются элементы при масштабирвоании html

Tags: html5

[image: сдвигаются элементы при масштабирвоании html]

Как сделать чтобы элементы не съезжали при изменении масштаба страницы?
В данном примере кода речь идёт о белом квадрате

> `#sv{background-color:white;top:-309px;
>   left:99px;}`

Вот сам код:

```css
#sc,
#sd,
#sn,
#sv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#q {
  height: 202px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#sc {
  background-color: green;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#sd {
  background-color: black;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#sn {
  background-color: pink;
  top: -102px;
  left: 99px;
}

#sv {
  background-color: white;
  top: -309px;
  left: 99px;
}

#all {
  width: 585px;
}

#w {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 177px;
  width: 375px;
  padding: 24px 1px 0px 28px;
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
  top: -207px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#sb {
  background-color: red;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}

#sz,
#sk,
#sg {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
}

#sz {
  left: 318px;
}

#sk {
  left: 486px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#sg {
  left: 150px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0 auto">
  <div id="all">
    <div id="q">
      <div id="sc"></div>
      <div id="sd"></div>
      <div id="all">
        <div id="sn"></div>
        <div id="sv"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="w">
      <div id="sb">4</div>
    </div>
    <div id="sz">5</div>
    <div id="sk">6</div>
    <div id="sg">7</div>
```

Comment: В кратце опишите - что это за вакханалия??? и почему тут тонны смещений?

Comment: это вакханалия  неопытного начинающего изучать нтмл гражданина

Comment: ребят я знаю что код кривой г.вно ламерский и всё такое ,просто скажите как сделать чтобы не смещался кубик и всё

Comment: Html покажи........

Comment: добавил код  хтмл

Comment: `z-index` работает только тогда, когда данному элементу заданы  `position absolute, fixed, relative`.

Comment: И еще,  о каком масштабировании идет речь?

Comment: `ID` - на странице может быть только в единственном экземпляре... Не может быть двух одинаковых `id` у разных элементов и и двух разных `id` у одного элемента

Comment: масштабирование = изменение масштаба в браузере клавишами ctrl+(+) и ctrl+(-)

Comment: А позволь спросить,  на кой тебе это масштабирование?

Comment: если верстать сайт по псд макету тоже будет смещение при масштабировании и клиент это наверняка заметит и попросит исправить

Comment: И еще `left top bottom right` тоже не работают без `position absolute, fixed, relative`

Comment: По масштабированию верстку не делают...  Брось это дело...  А что касается адаптивности сайта, на разные мониторы планшеты и телефоны, для этого существуют  медиа запросы `@media`

Comment: мда...............

Comment: Если в кратце, то странно, что только один блок съехал. Тут фишка в том, что тонны позиционирования перекрывающего друг друга. От того и будут различные ошибки. Откройте в хроме по правому клику (посмотреть код) и глядите как браузер видит ваши блоки, там я думаю ещё больше приколов увидите